Flutter Isar Database V3.1.0+1 Namespace Not Defined
I was using Isar Database in my Flutter application. with the latest Flutter update I made
'* What went wrong:
An exception occurred while implementing the plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']

Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check'.
The minimum supported Gradle version is 8.0. The current version is 7.4.2. If you are using gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/oguzaytar/Desktop/tfon_mobile/tfonmobile/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-8.0-all.zip.
I am getting an error like this.
When I change the gradle version of the application to 8.x, the isar_flutter_libs dependency does not have a namespace property, so I get the error ;

'There was a problem configuring project ':isar_flutter_libs'.

Failed to create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
The namespace is not specified. Please specify a namespace in the module's build.gradle file as follows:

 android {
     namespace 'com.example.namespace'
 }

I get an error like '.
I could not find a solution.
I forked the Isar Package and made the changes here (I changed the AGP version to 8.x and added Namespace) but I got an error that the IsarLink property is not defined.
It is not possible to use it as given in the documentation.

By adding the following code block to the android/build.gradle file content
An exception occurred while implementing a plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
I have fixed the error.
subprojects {
  // fix for verifyReleaseResources
  // ============
  afterEvaluate { project ->
    if (project.plugins.hasPlugin(“com.android.application”) ||
      project.plugins.hasPlugin(“com.android.library”)) {
      project.android {
        compileSdkVersion 34
        buildToolsVersion “34.0.0”
      }
    }
    if (project.hasProperty(“android”)) {
      project.android {
        if (namespace == null) {
          namespace project.group
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // ============
  project.buildDir = “${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}”
  project.evaluationDependsOn(“:app”)
}


The main isar package is quite outdated, you can try community version
 isar:
    hosted:
      name: isar
      url: https://pub.isar-community.dev/
    version: ^3.0.0

  isar_flutter_libs:
    hosted:
      name: isar_flutter_libs
      url: https://pub.isar-community.dev/
    version: ^3.0.0
   

dev_dependencies:
  isar_generator:
    hosted:
      name: isar_generator
      url: https://pub.isar-community.dev/
    version: ^3.0.0


